# AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am getting an error that seems... wrong. Because of course worksheet object has set_column() as a function, it's in the docs. I've probably done something dumb like drop a parenthesis.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrubaddresses.py", line 137, in <module>
    run()
  File "scrubaddresses.py", line 118, in run
    format_col_width(worksheet)
  File "scrubaddresses.py", line 24, in auto_format_cell_width
    ws.set_column('B:C', 20)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'
```

Here's my ridiculous import. Config is some constants, controller has some helper functions.

```
from smartystreets_python_sdk import StaticCredentials, exceptions, Batch, ClientBuilder
from smartystreets_python_sdk.us_street import Lookup as StreetLookup
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import config
from controller import getExcel, clean
```

The func in question:

```
def format_col_width(ws):
    ws.set_column('B:C', 20)
    ws.set_column('D', 1)
    ws.set_column('E', 20)
```

Where the ws being passed comes from:

```
            df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
            print(df1)

            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet, index = False, engine='xlsxwriter')
            worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet]
            format_col_width(worksheet)
```

Did I forget to import something? Xlsxwriter is installed.

Answer (score 18):

The reason it gives: `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'`

This is because you have not installed xlsxwriter on your PC.

you can use:

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

and it will work isa.

Comment: Worst error message ever. You saved me hours.

Comment: THIS ANSWER should be accepted !
Cant believe that this was the solution, without any error messages displayed or smth similar. Crazy. Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in the single column ranges. They should be `D:D` instead of `D` since the method needs a start and end column even if they are the same.

With that modification the code should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

def format_col_width(ws):
    ws.set_column('B:C', 20)
    ws.set_column('D:D', 1)
    ws.set_column('E:E', 20)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format_col_width(worksheet)

writer.save()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Try the above code and see if it works. If it doesn't then XlsxWriter may not be installed and Pandas is defaulting to OpenPyXL.

Comment: I changed it, but unfortunately that's not the problem - the error is on the first line, 
`
File "scrubaddresses.py", line 24, in auto_format_cell_width
    ws.set_column('B:C', 20)
`
I did run pip install xlsxwriter, and nothing changed. Maybe i should reboot and try again, lol.

Weirdly enough, I ran your code as test.py and it threw no errors.

Comment: I have figured it out - it was using xlwt, as I am working with .xls files.

Comment: Good one. I'll look out for that in future.

Comment: The D:D is making a smiley with an upside down hat

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, the following worked for me:

```
def format_col_width(ws):
    ws.column_dimensions['B'].width = 20
    ws.column_dimensions['C'].width = 20
    ws.column_dimensions['D'].width = 1
    ws.column_dimensions['E'].width = 20
```

Comment: This works for me thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
    # monkey path :) -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844262/how-can-i-solve-error-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-float-in-python
    # as of 2023/04/21
    # AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'
    np.float = float  
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') 
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, na_rep='NaN')
    for column in df:
        column_length = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
        #writer.sheets['Sheet1'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_length)  <-- set_column deprecated
        writer.sheets['Sheet1'].column_dimensions[chr(65+col_idx)].width = column_length + 5   # add some extra space {5 here} to have a better look
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).