# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, complex-numbers

I am trying to make a real number complex using numpy. I am using numpy version `1.24.3`

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
c=np.complex(1)
```

However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'.
```

Comment: Similar to [How can I solve error "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844262/how-can-i-solve-error-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-float-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.complex` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `complex`.

Instead of `np.complex` you can use:

```
complex(1)         #output (1+0j)

#or

np.complex128(1)   #output (1+0j)

#or

np.complex_(1)     #output (1+0j)

#or

np.cdouble(1)      #output (1+0j)
```

Link to doc: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations