# writing with openpyxl to existing excel file

Tags: python, numpy

- 

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = output_filename)
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
ws.cell(row=1,column=1).value = "write_lol"
wb.save(output_filename)
```

- 

this creates the following error. The rest of the program is not important. this is a relatively simple program that should work. I have the modules installed. Im using pycharm

```
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\Desktop\pythonProject\main.py", line 646, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY, PANDAS
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .strings import (
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\strings.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .numbers import NUMERIC_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\numbers.py", line 49, in <module>
    numpy.float,
  File "C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'cfloat'?
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [100] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [200] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [300] is turned on
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.  It looks like your error is truncated.

Comment: Post full traceback and the full code that fails, let others decide what's important and what not or create a MRE that throws the same error.

Comment: did it thanks..

Comment: Update your packages. The error shows a compatibility warning which means you're using outdated packages. If you search for ```np.float`` was a deprecated alias for the builtin ``float``` you'll find a lot of results, and around 450 SO questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve error "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844262/how-can-i-solve-error-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-float-in-python)

Comment: updated openpyxl, and fixed issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflict in the numpy version the method you are trying to implement is np.float that feature is deprecated and introduced some more advance features. you can use python's float or turn your numpy version down to use it. basically it's package problem of openpyxl it self you have to go to the file mention in the debug log and there you have to implement the float conflict fix.

Comment: how can i change the code to fix issue?

Comment: updated openpyxl, and fixed issue