# Loading video using scikit-video latest version and numpy latest version gives numpy has no float attribute error

Tags: python, numpy, video, scikits

I have installed the latest version of `scikit-video=1.1.11` and the latest version of `numpy=1.26.1`. When trying to load a video as

```
>>> import skvideo.io
>>> skvideo.io.vread('video_path.mp4')
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/snb/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skvideo/io/io.py", line 144, in vread
    reader = FFmpegReader(fname, inputdict=inputdict, outputdict=outputdict, verbosity=verbosity)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/snb/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skvideo/io/ffmpeg.py", line 44, in __init__
    super(FFmpegReader,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/snb/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skvideo/io/abstract.py", line 87, in __init__
    if np.float(parts[1]) == 0.:
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/snb/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 324, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations. Did you mean: 'cfloat'?
```

The error goes away if I install older version of `numpy=1.23.5` as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74864409/3337089). The answer notes that `float` attribute is deprecated in `numpy=1.20` and removed in `numpy=1.24`.

So, why has `scikit-video` not updated this in their latest version? Is there no way to use latest `numpy` with `scikit-video`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [open issue in the scikit-video github repository](https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video/issues/154#issuecomment-1445239790).

One possible solution (as proposed in that issue) is using

```
import numpy
numpy.float = numpy.float64
numpy.int = numpy.int_
```

Or using an older numpy version as you proposed.

As far as I see, there is no special reason for it apart from that this change in numpy has not been taken into account yet. Please not that the newest version of scikit-video is from 2018.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Any idea if `scikit-video` is still in development or is it better to switch to some other library for reading/writing videos?

Comment: Well there have been some updates on the github in the last months: https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video
This even includes some changes for numpy >= 1.24. So I would say it is not abandoned but I cannot say if its still in active development. Even if it is not, there is no reason to not use it as long as it does what you need.